# Webgl weird rendering with simple texture

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl, textures

I'm having trouble rendering textures on my custom 3D shape.

With the following parameters:

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT);
gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

It gives me this result:

[image: result]

Changing the following parameters:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT);
```

It gives me this :

[image: result2]

And with these parameters:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

[image: result3]

I tried changing the texture coordinates but without success the one used for each face here was:
    `0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 10.0,
    10.0, 10.0,
    10.0, 0.0`

Any idea why one triangle(actually 2 the one on the parallel face) behaves weirdly?

Comment: If you have a link to the full code that would help.

Comment: here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/bNTkK/6/

Comment: What do you want it to look like? Most likely you're going to need to repeat vertices because you'll need different texture coordinates on each triangle to get the look you want.

Comment: if you look at the first picture, the triangle in red should have the same texture as any other triangles, why my chess texture does not apply correctly there?
Let's say this face have points 1,2,3,4,5, I'm creating triangles like that: 1-2-3, 1-3-4, 1-4-5.
And apparently the last one created is the one with the weird texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using faces with varying amount of points - but still using a fixed number (4) of texture coords for a face. As some faces have 5 points, at some point the texture coords are "shifted".

Instead, you should add them just like the vertices:

```
for (var j=0; j < face.length; j++){
    vertices...

     //generate texture coords, they could also be stored like the points
     textureCoords.push(points[face[j]][0] / 4);
     textureCoords.push((points[face[j]][1]+points[face[j]][2]) / 4);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bNTkK/9/